# How to use a String in a FutureBuilder as Future<String> (Flutter - Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I want to use a String in a FutureBuilder's future value. But if this String is null then I want to use the String from any restful API.

That's why I want to use a String as Future< String > in FutureBuilder.

So, How can I do it, and is it possible?

Comment: What have you done so far? Please provide the important code snippets.

Comment: I didn't do anything till now. But I want to know that, how to use a String as Future< String >.

Comment: It would be better if you tried it first before asking here in stackoverflow. If you still don't have any idea on how `Future` works, please read https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await. For `FutureBuilder`, please read https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip `FutureBuilder` and use **`initState`** and load the `List` as shown below :

```
   List<String> webServiceList ;
  
  List<String> localList = [ 'Foo' ,'Foo' , 'Foo' , 'Foo'] ;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: webServiceList != null ? ListView.builder(
          itemCount:webServiceList.length,
          itemBuilder: (_ , index){
            return Text(webServiceList[index]);
            
          }) : ListView.builder(
          itemCount:localList.length,
          itemBuilder: (_ , index){
            return Text(localList[index]);

          }),

    );
  }

  void loadData() async{

    webServiceList = await ///Get data for web services API ; 

    setState(() {
      
    });
    
  }
```

Comment: I think it is not a good idea. Because, in your code, I have to write the ListView two time and it is not good for a big ListView. Instead, I want to write the ListView one time in a FutureBuilder and give the string as the future value and if the string is null then it will fetch the api.